# Notepad ++: how to replace specific text in lines with different values?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm modifying a game. I want to change certain numbers but I need to do it in a specific way.

For example:

> soldier          Jinetes, 24, 0, 1

I want to replace the number 24 but not alter any other value in the line but also alter every other line containing the number 24 and beginning with soldier.

So any line that looks like this:

> soldier NAME, 24, #, #

Without affecting anything else in that line and being able to do so regardless of the name or other values in that line.

Can I do that? How can I do that?

Comment: The only way to do this that makes sense is indeed by using Regular Expressions. Yet, learning to use them comes with a steep learning curve. You're lucky @wlod provided a solution, but understanding it and being able to make changes to it might be challenging. Just wanted to let you know that this is the *only* way to do this. There's not realy an alternative...

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++ regular expressions use the standard **PCRE**](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

I've used the online editor [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) with the FLAVOR selected to '**pcre**'. The same regular expression worked like charm in N++.

The dummy input I've used:

```
soldier NAME1, 24, 0, 1
soldier NAME2, 25, 1, 2
soldier NAME3, 26, 2, 3
soldier NAME4, 27, 3, 4
soldier NAME5, 28, 4, 5
soldier NAME6, 29, 5, 6
soldier NAME7, 30, 6, 7
machine NAME8, 24, 7, 8
Xsoldier NAME9, 24, 8, 9
soldier NAME10, 24, 9, 10
```

Expected output:
Only first and last line should be modified. The number '24' should be replaced with a new value.

The regex expression:

```
^soldier\s+(?:[^\,]+\,\s+)\K24(?=\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+)
```

Now you can use standard Ctrl+H, 'Find what' should be filled with the expression and 'Replace with' with the new value. Make sure that 'Wrap around' is checked and also 'Search Mode' is set to 'Regular expression'.

Clicking on 'Replace All' will replace all numbers '24' with a new specified value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a [Regular Expression](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Also see [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: This is just links to general information rather than an actionable solution to the question, so it would be more appropriate as a comment.  But even if it was links to a solution, external links can break, in which case the answer would have no value.  Answers should be self-contained; the links are only for attribution and supplemental reference.